# How can i insert data into database using custom controller method or any other way in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to scrap data from some web page and insert it into database. I got only one table in database called Product that contains ProductID,ProductName,ProductPrice like u can see from model generated using ADO.net Entity Data Model

```
public partial class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

I am new to asp.net mvc(started learning it 3 days ago)so it confuses me a bit ,and cant figure it out where to make new method for scrapping data and putting it into database.
I was trying to make new ActionResult ScrapData() method in ProductController but when it comes to db.SaveChanges() i get ValidationError

```
public ActionResult ScrapData()
{

    List<Product> product = new List<Product>();
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.idea.rs/Proizvodi");
    foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='g2 bp_l_1of4 bp_m_1of3 bp_s_1of2 bp_xs_1of1 item  ']"))
    {
        Product p = new Product();
        p.ProductName = node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='item_title']").InnerText;
        p.ProductPrice = node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='price']").InnerText;

        product.Add(p);

    }

        for (int i = 0; i < product.Count; i++)
    {
        db.Products.Add(product[i]);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }

    return View(db.Products.ToList());

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exact error you are getting ? post here

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: What are the `ValidationErrors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create connection beetwen database model and your `Product` model.

For example your table `Products` try create in another class DBModel as:

```
namespace Your_NameSpace
    {
    [Table("Products")]
    public class Products
        {
           [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] \\ If you have identity set in table Products, if not remove this line
           [Key] // Primary key
           public int ProductID { get; set; }
           public string ProductName { get; set; }
           public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
        }
     }
```

And for the next step in your controller in loop use:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < product.Count; i++)
            {
                 var DBModel = new Products();
                 DBModel.ProductName = product[i].ProductName;
                 DBModel.ProductPrice = product[i].ProductPrice;
                 db.Products.Add(DBModel);
            }

        db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the db.SaveChanges() outside the loop i.e :

```
for (int i = 0; i < product.Count; i++)
{
    db.Products.Add(product[i]);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Why do you? It would be better performance wise but it won't fix the error he is getting

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Mapper (automapper) to map your model product to you entity Db.Products.

or you can do this manually

```
    for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
                {
                     var product= new Products();
                     product.ProductName = product[i].ProductName;
                     product.ProductPrice = product[i].ProductPrice;
                     db.Products.Add(product);
                }

 db.SaveChanges();
```

Or you can try this

```
   foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='g2 bp_l_1of4 bp_m_1of3 bp_s_1of2 bp_xs_1of1 item  ']"))
        {
            Products p = new Product();
            p.ProductName = node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='item_title']").InnerText;
            p.ProductPrice = node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='price']").InnerText;

             db.Products.Add(p);

        }
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you all for such a fast help... i menaged to get it work when i made new project and redo all things from scratch it was something messed up cos i deleted many scaffolded items etc ...using Dawid's first part of code i generated controller and view for ScrapData and Kypaz idea to put db.SaveChanges() after loop it works like a charm now.